# Detecting that a function returned `void` (rather than `undefined`)

Tags: typescript, void

I heard a rumor that `void` means `null|undefined`. After all, this code is legal:

```
var x: void = undefined, y: void = null;
```

But I'm having a problem that defies this understanding.

**EDIT:** The problem disappeared when I restarted Visual Studio Code. It turns out that the problem described below occurs only if `strictNullChecks` is **off**. I use `"strictNullChecks": true` so I guess something confused the IDE momentarily, and it was surprising that new errors could be caused by a less strict mode. I should mention that in `strictNullChecks` mode, `var y: void = null` is an error. This just leaves me with one question: what's the difference between `void` and `undefined` in strict mode?

I wanted to define a callback for a data structure that *could* return a value, but *doesn't have to*. Specifically you can return `{stop:true}` to stop iterating. My code started like this, which didn't work in case the function didn't return a value:

```
type ForRangeResult = {stop?:boolean} | undefined;
class BTree<K=any,V=any> {
  forEach(callback: (k:K, v:V) => ForRangeResult): number { ... }
  ...
}

// Type 'void' is not assignable to type '{ stop?: boolean; }'.
new BTree().forEach((k,v) => {});
```

The error message (which itself seems incorrect) disappears if I use

```
type ForRangeResult = {stop?:boolean} | void;
```

But it comes back if I use

```
type ForRangeResult = {stop?:boolean} | undefined | null;
```

However, if I use `{stop?:boolean} | void`, how do I check whether the function returned `void`? The usual [control-flow-based typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#control-flow-based-type-analysis) doesn't work here:

```
var result = callback(keys[i], values[i]);
if (result !== undefined && result !== null) {
  // [ts] Property 'stop' does not exist on type 'void'
  if (result.stop)
    return ...;
}
```

I'm inclined to think this is either a compiler bug or an ill-conceived design decision, but is there some easy fix that I am missing?

**tsc --version**: 2.9.2 (unless IntelliSense version is different)

Comment: It works as expected with `strictNullChecks` turned on

Comment: Thanks for the hint; the error occurs when `strictNullChecks` is off.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[ORIGINAL ANSWER]

This form of your `if` test avoids the error:

```
if (result instanceof Object) {
```

[BETTER ANSWER]

```
if (x !== null && typeof x === 'object') {
```

This code will not generate compiler errors if `x` is of type `void` (undefined).

Comment: Thanks. I found out that the error should not occur when `strictNullChecks` is on (which is better for me because I wanted high performance and [tests](https://jsperf.com/instanceof-vs-typeof-vs-constructor-vs-member) [suggest](https://jsperf.com/detect-not-null-or-undefined) that comparing with `undefined` is faster than `instanceof Object`.)

Comment: This results in error: The left-hand side of an 'instanceof' expression must be of type 'any', an object type or a type parameter.ts(2358)
let result: void

Comment: @ Bobík I updated my answer